# Ruby: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Ran into this error message whilst developing tonight: `SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:`

I have two models:

- Podcasts have many Tracks
- Tracks belong to Podcasts.
- Podcast files are hosted on [mixcloud](http://www.mixcloud.com).

To create a Podcast:

- user submits a url for a podcast on mixcloud
- rails app grabs json feed associated with url
- json is used to set attributes (title, image etc) on the new Podcast object

I'm trying to get my rails app to take advantage of the fact that the json feed also details the names (and artists) of the Tracks that belong to this Podcast.

I thought the following before_validation method would automatically create all associated Tracks whenever we create a new Podcast.

```
class Podcast < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :mixcloud_url, :lots, :of, :other, :attrs
  has_many :tracks    
  before_validation :create_tracks
  def create_tracks
    json = Hashie::Mash.new HTTParty.get(self.json_url)    
    json.sections.each do |section|
      if section.section_type=="track"
          Track.create(:name=>section.track.name, :podcast_id=>self.id)
      end
    end             
  end
end
```

How can I get round this? It looks like rails (or sqlite3) doesn't like me creating new instances of an associated model in this way. How else can I do this? I suspect this is as much a rails problem as an sqlite3 one. I can post more code if it's gonna help.

Comment: ps - the error is shown when I submit a new podcast and I'm fairly sure my parsing of the feed is not the problem.

Comment: pps - :json_url is set in another before_validation method, I just didn't mention it, and it does work properly

Comment: AFAIK sqlite locks the entire database file (since it's the only one it's got) when manipulating data, so you might have a problem right there. Sqlite was not meant to be used by applications that have multiple concurrent users.

Comment: For me, the problem was that I had DB Browser for SQLite open.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

For anyone else encountering this issue with SQLite locking in development when a Rails console is open, try this:

Just run the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION; END;")
```

For me anyway, it appears to clear any transaction that the console was holding onto and frees up the database.

This is especially a problem for me when running delayed_job, which seems to fail at closing the transaction quite often.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to ruby and rails, could someone explain what i have to do with this line? I wasn't able to run it in cmd...

Comment: late to the party but for anyone with the same question as @AkshatSharda in the previous comment, just type `rails console` at the command line and then paste the ruby snippet above.

Answer (score 27):

SQLite is not really supposed to be used for concurrent access which is the issue you are running into here. You can try increasing the timeout in your `database.yml` file which may be a workaround for you in this case. However, I would recommend you switch to another database that supports multiple connections like MySQL or PgSQL.

Comment: Holy crap, changing the timeout to 3000000 fixed this. I did need to drop and migrate the db again, but as long as it works I'm happy. Thanks again.

Comment: Eh, just warning you that's sorta bad practice and it would really be advised that you move over to a regular database. However for development this should be OK.

Comment: yeah, I use PG in production (on heroku) where I doubt the issue will crop up and I can live with the limitations of SQLite3 in dev mode.

Comment: Adding the `:timeout => 1000` option solved my problem. I was having concurrent access and this lock was killing my application. thx

Answer (score 22):

For me...the issue I had was that it seemed that the Rails Console I had open for a while was locking up a connection with SQLite.

So once I exited that console, and restarted my webserver (Thin) it worked perfectly.

I tried @trisweb's suggestion but it didn't work for me.

Comment: was just on my way to make this comment! +1

Comment: Similar to this, if you have the SQLite DB Browser program open on your DB, you will get this issue.

Comment: Also, if you used ctrl+d on your mac, use fg to bring it back to the foreground and ctrl+c it.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is
>   locked: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name",
>   "password_digest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

issue. I tried every way around found in Google and I failed. The problem was solved for me when I closed my SQLite Database Browser.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have 2 guards or several consoles running.
If you want make sure desperately see the "No Name's" answer above.

You can also try increasing pool:

for example:
change test section in your config/database.yml as below

```
test:
    adapter: sqlite3
    database: db/test.sqlite3
    pool: 50
    timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably you have a Rails console open on another bash, if so you have to close it (ctrl+D).

Comment: not sure why this was down voted as its definitely one of the possible options.

Comment: this should have more upvotes. at least for me that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

actually for me, I found killing rails help to fix this problem.

use `"ps aux | grep rails"` to find out ongoing rails process id.
then use

```
"kill -9 [rails-pid]"
```

to kill processes.

Then it will work

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely not related to rails code. Using at the same time the console with the sandbox option (`rails console --sandbox`), makes the problem systematic with SQLite, since the console is basically waiting to quit to rollback everything.

The solution above from @trisweb will not work in this case, but quitting the console will.

Answer (score 1):

my trouble is: I opened a database management program named "DB Browser  for SQlite". Closed this database management program, and problem solved.

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is an old question and there are many answers on here already. But none of them worked for me, meaning it took me a long time to finally figure out the problem. **I found what worked and will share it in case it is what might be causing the problem for you too.**

I was using the SQLITE Browser (its a GUI database browser). I will refer to it as "GUI" here (to prevent confusion with the word browser being your localhost::8000 chrome browser or whatever.
http://sqlitebrowser.org/

I was monitoring what was being written to the database and had the GUI open while my rails app ran in my chrome browser. I would refresh the GUI to see if it was adding the data as I expected it to.

As a matter of debugging I had decided to delete a row from the SQLite GUI so I could see if my app would react appropriately to the row being missing now.

As it turns out, the SQLite Browser **does not actually delete the row** (causing confusion on my end as to why my app was acting like the row was still there, even though it was visually missing on the GUI). Anyway after 30 minutes of frustration I closed the SQLite GUI and then got a notice that asked if i wanted to save any changes to the database that I made. **I naively clicked "No"** and closed the app.

Apparently what happens is that the GUI then locked the database because there were rows in my database that had been sort of "soft-deleted" without committing to the delete. So the GUI was (for lack of a better term) holding the database in Limbo.

This explains why **a)** my app wasnt acting like the row was missing, because it hadn't actually been deleted yet, and **B)** explains why the database locked up. It was still waiting for me to commit the deletes.

So to solve the problem, I simply opened up the GUI once again and deleted the same row and then closed the GUI and this **time I clicked "Yes" when asking to save changes to the database**. It saved the delete and unlocked the database and now my app works!

---

*I hope this helps someone else that might be having the same issue but was using the SQLite Browser GUI interface. This might be what is locking your database.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For those with SQLite Database Browser. I did not need to close SQLite Database Browser. I only had to click the "Write Changes" button. It is highlighted and needs to not be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has troubles with concurrency.
I changed sqlite on Postgresql and the issue is gone

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you make any changes manually directly into the SQlite DB Browser (like delete a row or change the value of any column) and forget to save those changes. Any changes made need to be saved (`ctrl + s`). If not saved, SQLite locks the Database until u save those changes.

I did the same and my issue got resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I was using [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and rails console simultaneously. Closing the `DB Browser for SQLite` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting the server 
or closing any running rails console,
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your .sqlite3 file must be saved.
Go to DB Browser for SQlite and make ctrl+s or File->Write Changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap cycle in a single transaction:

```
  def create_tracks
    json = Hashie::Mash.new HTTParty.get(self.json_url)    
    Track.transaction do
      json.sections.each do |section|
        if section.section_type=="track"
          Track.create(:name=>section.track.name, :podcast_id=>self.id)
        end
      end
    end             
  end
```

(see **Track.transaction**)

Answer (score 0):

You may also have enabled threads when parallelizing your tests. Remember to disable the option in `test/test_helper.rb` :

```
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)
```

to

```
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)
```

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#parallel-testing-with-threads

Answer (score 0):

```
1. bin/rails console 
2. exit
```

Go into the ***rails console*** and type ***exit***, and press ***enter***.
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, many of these solutions did not work for me.

I was lucky. Since this was happening while I was running tests, I just did a simple `DROP` and `CREATE` on the DB.

```
$ rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
Dropped database 'db/test.sqlite3'

$ rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
Created database 'db/test.sqlite3'

$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
== 20220310061725 Tables: migrating ======================================
  ....
== 20220310061725 Tables: migrated (0.0027s) =============================
...etc
```

Not the best solution, but it works in a pinch.

If this was in your development environment, and you HAD to do this, I would seriously invest in creating a data `seed` for your DBs so you can get up to speed again.

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to talk about the case of rails  controller opened.

In my own case, I had opened rails controller with the --sandbox option.
After reading that I had to close the rails console. Closing alone didn't fix it. I had to restart my PC to make sure all processes got terminated. That resolved it.