# Rails 3.2.13: Create method not working on a model in cloned rails app from github

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, github

I've cloned a remote repo containing a rails app from Github, and I'm getting unfamiliar errors when trying to create and save objects to the database.

I've made a signup form to create a new user (called Mentor, here) and instead of creating on submit, I'm getting errors that all the fields are blank and when I check the server logs, I'm seeing this instead of the normal `INSERT INTO` (also happens using `Mentor.create` in rails console as well):

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
 Mentor Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "mentors" WHERE "mentors"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

I have already run `rails new ~/cloned_repo` so all of the requisite rails files should have been created.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**Update with controller code:**

```
 def new
   @mentor = Mentor.new
 end

 def create
  @mentor = Mentor.new(params[:Mentor])
   if @mentor.save
     session[:mentor_id] = @mentor.id
     redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
   else
     render "new"
   end
 end
```

Comment: It might help to share some of your `mentors_controller.rb` code.  Also the rollback is happening due to the email address exists for a Mentor already.  You must have a validation for the email to be unique and an item is in the table with that same email address.

Comment: When I call `Mentor.all` in rails console I get an empty array. I haven't created any data in the application yet because of this issue.

Comment: Try changing `params[:Mentor])` to `params[:mentor]`.

Comment: Ah! stupid mistake. Looks like it's getting further now, but it still failed with `SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked`

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11529884/1335437

Comment: @l34p3r it's a common rule here - answers that solved your issue should be accepted so this question in the list would appear as solved.

Comment: Yeah I know the rule. Now that I see the formal answer I will accept it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `params[:Mentor])` to `params[:mentor]`

Comment: Also, for future reference, the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION; END;")` was essential to solving the problem as well.