# What does the "database is locked" error message mean in Ruby on Rails testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following Hartl's Rails Tutorial and using Rails 6. I keep getting persistent errors that seem to pop up at random whenever I run tests - random because the consecutive tests sometimes indicate errors in different areas. These tests are also very very slow - > 30 minutes sometimes. Has anyone encountered this? What could I be doing wrong? And now for the red herring: I am using Win 8.1 :)

The common thing about these errors messages is that they all contain a "RuntimeErroer: database is locked" message. Here's one of them:

```rb
ERROR["test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses", 
#<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x000000000c9b29c0 @name="UserTest">, 608.7059665989946]
 test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses#UserTest (608.71s)
RuntimeError: RuntimeError: database is locked
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using SQLite database? Sometimes Rails Console will lock database, this is common issue for SQLite database. Try running tests with console closed

Comment: did you checked these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154664/ruby-sqlite3busyexception-database-is-locked

Comment: @nuak, I am using SQLite with rails console closed.

Answer (score 4):

I've been fighting this same error for quite sometime. It actually go so bad it roadblocked me from really moving forward in Hartl's Rails Tutorial.

Edit: Found a much better answer that simply resolves the problem instead of playing with settings I probably don't really understand.

See -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62730905/10463184

My only contribution, as a windows user, I found that commenting out the entire line in test/test_help.rb...

```rb
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)
```

Resolved the issue. Trying the setting suggested at the link resulted in a "UNIXServer is required (LoadError)" error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to one of my challenges - the interminablly slow test speed. In the config/database.yml I added (to the test.sqlite part) the following lines:

```
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 3000
```

The test duration dropped from minutes to mere seconds. Victory!

Alas, the "RuntimeError: database is locked" messages are still there, however.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation.

In my case this error happened because the tests run in parallel by default on MiniTest, which means that they also run in parallel in rails. When this happens and there are tests that make transactions on the tests db, the db locks itself causing the error.

The solution that worked for me was setting the attribute "use_transactional_tests" to false in the test class.

You can see the proper usage and an example in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-parallel-transactions).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else makes the obvious mistake that I did, be sure to exit out of any rails console sessions in your terminals before trying to delete on your live site or in testing.