# database is locked in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

> Error:
> CategoryTest#test_name_should_be_unique:
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked
> test/models/category_test.rb:18:in `block in class:CategoryTest'

Can someone please help me with this error I'm getting?
It was working till a little while ago and suddenly this showed up. I had no errors in my test.
I'm new to Stack Overflow so if I'm doing something in the wrong way, just take it easy.

Comment: Have you done any edit lately to your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION; END;")`

Full discussion: [Ruby: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154664/ruby-sqlite3busyexception-database-is-locked)