# Database is getting locked when saving my record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, carrierwave, image-upload

I am getting the database is locked when trying to save my record. I am trying a simple blog in rails. Having an article model, that contains the attribute, title, image and content. I have not encountered this error before. I am using carrierwave as the image uploader gem. Pls, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the error image
[image]

the image uploader file

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :full do
    process resize_to_fit: [650, 650]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [200, 200]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

end
```

Article model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_presence_of :title, :text
  
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154664/ruby-sqlite3busyexception-database-is-locked)

Comment: It doesn't as I have ran through the solution before posting this

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a real database if you can, Postgres works great with Rails, Mysql too, both are quite easy to set up.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and its working now

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is specific to `CarrierWave`, but more the sqlite database you are working with / logic in your controller. First you are calling sqlite queries before you insert and not wrapping them in a transaction. `current_user.articles` may be calling *many* `select` statements dependant on how many articles they have which could be locking the `insert` statement so I would look at changing this if you want to continue using sqlite.

Sqlite is nefarious for locking on concurrent access. Whilst it is a fantastic piece of software, a more suitable DBMS like MySQL should be used and it's super easy to setup for local development in a docker container. If you want to save yourself some pain and setup MySQL I've included a little example below.

If you want to stay with sqlite you should open up a console on the database and `vacuum` it. I find extended development on such databases bloats and you should reclaim some unused space which *generally* assists with performance.

Lastly, sometimes sqlite files lock up thinking a ghost process is writing to them and restoring the database is one way to fix this. Check by running a simple select command directly on the database (*I don't think this would be happening to you if you can view data in forms etc*) but just in case, if the command returns true you can dump *in bash* using the following: `echo '.dump' | sqlite3 xxx.db.locked | sqlite3 xxx.db.dumped`

Setting up MySQL *insert the below into the corresponding files and run `docker-compose up` if using bash*

```
# Gemfile
gem 'mysql2'

# docker-compose.yml
mysql_repo:
  image: percona:5.7.25
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=machine_host
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql

# database.yml
mysql_defaults: &mysql_default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: 0.0.0.0
  port: 3306
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *mysql_default
  database: repo_development

test:
  <<: *mysql_default
  database: repo_test

production:
  <<: *mysql_default
  database: repo_production
```

Comment: Changing the database did it for me as I switched to postgres