# 'SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked' Exception on upload via carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I trying to use carrierwave gem for upload image in Ruby on rails.
following guid and try upload but, some error on my rails. i think caused database timeout, but i don't know what exactly.
here's my error screen.
I checked my uploader in model class and other things..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Qe6.png)

Comment: Which version of ruby and  rails, are you using ? I never used carrierwave but I know that paperclip is now deprecated and it's better to use activestorage. You could take a look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activestorage/README_md.html.
For the database error if it is locked it's maybe because something already locked it for writing something

Comment: @Snoobie I using rails 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite3 is a file-based database, and locking is little less advanced than a full fledged DB; I would only use it in a few users setting. Maybe you have opened the DB in a SQLite viewer or another process that is locking the DB at the same time?

There are plenty of suggestions in this thread: [Ruby: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154664/ruby-sqlite3busyexception-database-is-locked/11529884#11529884)