# Instance variable in view stays empty in Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, bdd

I have a page that's rendering lots of stuff when I really use it, but renders nothing in Capybara.

Controller goes like this:

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @ideas = Idea.all
  end
```

Relevant bit of the page goes like this:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
  Ideas length is <%= @ideas.length %>.
  <% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <%= link_to(idea.title, '#idea_' + idea.id.to_s, class: "accordion-toggle", data: {toggle: "collapse", parent: "#accordion"}  ) %>
      </div>
      <%= div_for(idea, class: "accordion-body collapse") do %>
          <div class="accordion-inner">
            <%= render :partial => "idea", locals: { :idea => idea } %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When viewed in Development, this works beautifully and I get loads of stuff in the view (my db is full of mock data). But when I pop it open mid-test using `save_and_open_page`, it's completely empty, and says "Ideas length is 0".

I did `rake db:test:clone` and `rake db:test:prepare`, but nada -- stays empty.

Can you help me figure out why? Is there a way to peek into the test db and see if anything's there?

**Edit:** Inspired by the comments, I realized the trouble must be that the test environment flushes things out every time, so obviously there's nothing. In an (apparently misguided) attempt to resolve this, I did:

```
  before do
    create(:idea)
    visit root_path
    click_link "Log In"
  end
```

Note the `create(:idea)` line, which was supposed to trigger my Idea factory and stick a mock idea into the db (the factory works fine with other tests).

Now the page says:

Internal Server Error

SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "provider", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

which is beyond weird. `Rails s` is running in the background.

As requested by commenter, full spec follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Idea page", js: true do

  subject { page }

  before do
    create(:idea)
    visit root_path
    click_link "Log In"
  end

  context "Single idea" do
    before do
      save_and_open_page
        #click_link('Eligendi sint quod quia alias sed sit vitae repellendus.')
    end

    it { should have_selector('a',text:'Claim') }

  end


end
```

Comment: Are you creating Idea objects before your page is visited? Within a point in your test you can just do `p Idea.all` or `p Idea.count` to get that info outputted to your console. You can also use Pry, if you're using that gem. You can run `rails c test` to get in to the Rails console for the test environment.

Comment: Do you use `database_cleaner` gem?

Comment: in your spec do:  `puts Idea.all` to see if you have any Ideas.  Also, it would help if you added your spec code to this question.

Comment: @MrDanA: I use Pry, and thanks for the tip. `p Idea.count` does come up empty. I don't mind trying to create the idea in the test (although I'd rather if it was a fixture), but that's not working either.

Comment: @dimuch: I do. Good tip. I'm now trying to create an idea within the spec but it's not working.

Comment: @ipd: Full spec added above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the data using a factory is the correct approach. To fix the sqlite error, you might need to increase the timeout for the database.

To do this, in `config/database.yml`

Find the `test:` environment and set

`timeout:`

To a larger value. As recommended by the question [SQLite3::BusyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78801/sqlite3busyexception)

After that, ensure that in `spec/spec_helper.rb` that you have the following line:

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

And that you are using something like database_cleaner to keep your test db clean between tests.

Comment: I've upped it like crazy (500000) but now the browser window is just spinning in the login page, "Waiting for 127.0.0.1 ..."

Comment: I would make sure that you have `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` and if you don't, try it. If that fixes your issue, or at least changes it, be sure to add in the `database_cleaner` gem or something equivalent.

Comment: I do have database_cleaner enabled. Do I still need that `transactional_fixtures` line? If so, where does it go? (What file?)

Comment: `spec/spec_helper.rb` and yes, you need it. The problem might be that because capybara is running in a different thread than your rails environment, if transactional fixtures are on only one can access the db at a time. With MySQL this presents as only one thread seeing the data.