# Rails - Most efficient way to save multiple params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Is there a more efficient way to write this controller code?  This handles a form that passes a name and description field and then saves it in my model.  I'm wondering if there is a way to pass all of the params at once, rather than specifying each one, as long as they match a column in my model.  Thanks for your help!

Controller:

```
def new
   @new_company = Company.new
   @new_company.name = params[:name]
   @new_company.description = params[:description]
   @new_company.save
end
```

View:

```
<form action="/checklist/new" method="post">

  <label>Company Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name"/>

  <label>Company Description</label>
  <input type="text" name="description"/>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to write it in your CREATE action, not in the NEW

```
def create
   @company = Company.new(params[:company])
   @company.save
end
```

New should look like this:

```
   def new
      @company = Company.new    
   end
```

Also, instead of writting html for your forms, do it the Rails way:

```
<%= form_for(@company) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name , "Company Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :description, "Company Description"%>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

To understand everything better I would suggest you this book:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/
or this short tutorial:
http://railsforzombies.org/levels/1

Comment: Thanks Zippie.  I'm getting a strange error when I try this.  SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "companies" ("created_at", "description", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: @Jason that probably means something else is using it.... `rails console` perhaps or SQLite Database Browser, I'm guessing

Comment: Yeah, it is something else, look at the second answer here, it helped me once : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78801/sqlite3busyexception

Comment: You're right it was the Browser.  Never run into that before, thanks.  It's now throwing me a undefined method `model_name' caused by the first line of the new form code, but I'll google around and see what I can come up with to fix that.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: add the new method to fix that. I wrote it in my answer

Comment: Replace `@new_company` with `@company`, in your controller. The names must match with the form.

Comment: Ups, thanx Leito for correcting me, i got caught up looking at his code

Comment: Yeah it's in there, still throwing it.  I have create and new methods.  I'm wondering if the problem is on the view side.  I've tried the form on both the new and create views but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: I figured it out.. was missing resources :companies from my routes!  Ha.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)