# RailsTutorial Chap 6, Rake Aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake

in the railstutorial chap.6 when I try to migrate I get this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Stephane-Cedroni:sample_app stephanecedroni$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
==  AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrating ===========================================
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0020s
==  AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrated (0.0022s) ==================================

rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: commit transaction/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:97:in `close'
```

Has someone had the same error?
I'm not very experimented, need your help!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78801/sqlite3busyexception

Comment: tried to fix it that but does not work..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I had another open console window where I was running "rails console --sandbox", so I prevented any changes to my database. After closing this window I could make a migration.

Maybe this will help you!